# Darker weight paint colors (Blender 2.8)

Tags: weight-painting

Weight paint from Blender 2.79 (shown in Blender 2.8)

[image: Neon colored weight painted scaled cube]

Weight paint created in Blender 2.8

[image: Darker colored weight painted scaled cube]

Is this a problem? Also, if not, is there a way to change it back to the neon colored weight paint so that I'm able to see it better?

EDIT:

I tried tweaking up the custom colors, but they are still dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so dark for me I don't know the reason why yours is. But it is adjustable you will find a colorramp for it in the preferences.
[image]

May be you messed up something here:

[image]

Comment: The colors are still dark.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I switched the color to object and it works just fine. Please edit your answer explaining the solution before I count it as solved.